# Permanently remove ethernet drivers in live mode, before installation

Tags: drivers, ethernet

I have a problem with the ethernet modules on my computer. I have a hardware defect that causes the computer to freeze on installation when the ethernet drivers are installed. This is not a problem, because I use routed internet on the PC. However, to install the system, I need to remove such ethernet drivers (before installing, preferably from the installation ISO itself, before creating the bootable pendrive). On Windows, I can do this through the WinReducer software. By removing all ethernet drivers in the program and saving the ISO to a bootable pendrive, I can install the system normally.  But I don't know how to remove the ethernet drivers from a Linux ISO. Specifically Xubuntu, which is the system I want to install. Is there any way to permanently remove the ethernet drivers in live mode, or remove them from the installation ISO before creating a bootable pendrive?

Thank you for the response.